# Why do laptop batteries and chargers differ in voltage output?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charger

As an example, my laptop's charger gives out 19,5V and 3.42Ah while it's battery gives out 11,1V and 2.2Ah, what's going on exactly?

Comment: According to the manufacturer and model, the parts in a laptop can change hence the voltage and current rating also.

Comment: @nidhin But this happens across every model, on every computer. I think there must be a reason for this.

Comment: The charger won't give out 3.42Ah. It'll give up to 3.42A continuously with no time limit. The battery capacity is 2.2Ah which means that at 2.2A it'll be flat in an hour, or at 1A it'll be flat in 2.2 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The battery's ratings are it's nominal voltage and capacity ratings.  The charger's ratings are the voltage it will supply and the maximum current that it can supply.

So the battery ratings don't tell you much about what it can supply to the laptop.  For example it doesn't tell you what current can be supplied by the battery.

You are probably also asking why the battery and charger are at different voltages.  Many possible reasons.  Less line losses to run at higher voltages and lower currents, but for a battery, it would require a large battery pack to run that high a voltage.  As a result there is a dc-dc converter in the laptop that converts the voltage to current and vice versa depending on whether you are using battery or plug in.